# QT creator with Cmake error

Tags: ros, package, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use QT creator with Cmake to compile the package,but it fails to find rosbuild.cmake.

please help me

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:
    /core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (rosbuild_init):
      Unknown CMake command "rosbuild_init".   
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Looking for Q_WS_X11
    -- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
    -- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
    -- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
    -- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
    -- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
    -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
    -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
    -- Found Qt4: /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.5")
    -- Boost version: 1.46.1
    -- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so 
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194179/qt-creator-with-cmake-error/) by [xiaoke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20388/xiaoke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-10-05**:
Which ros version / which operating system do you use?

**Comment by [xiaoke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20388/xiaoke/) on 2014-10-06**:
I  installed ROS Fuerte Turtle on Ubuntu 12.04 of linux system. Thank you all the same !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error appears if the ROS environment is not set correctly when starting QtCreator. The most frequent reason is if you started QtCreator from one of the Ubuntu menus or a desktop link. The solution is easy: Either start from a ROS environment enabled terminal, or create a dedicated desktop file. Both options are described in detail on the [IDEs ROS wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xiaoke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20388/xiaoke/) on 2014-10-06**:
Your answer is very effective.Thank you !